# How to move sprite continously between two object

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, boolean, box2d-iphone

I have 3 sprites A, B, and C.

A and C are objects...

B is Enemy sprites... so the design is below. I need B to move continously between A and C.

**A**----------**B**----------**C**

I use the below method in an Update method. So that methods gets called for each frame.

```
ABcollision
{
if(Aistouched == YES)
{
Bvelocity.x = 5;  /// moves my sprite B right side
}
}

CBcollision
{
if(Cistouched == YES)
{
Bvelocity.x = -5; /// moves my sprite B right side
}
}
```

My update method to update velocity:

```
   b2Vec2 dins = dinobody->GetLinearVelocity();
   dinobody->SetLinearVelocity(Bvelocity);
```

The above code makes my sprite B move left and right only once.

Comment: can you also provide code for your moving method? the problem probably lies with not having a previous step. create a a new variable name previousStep and every time before you update your position with Bvelocity, update previousStep with Bvelocity and if there is a collision, bring B one step backward before changing velocity.

Comment: i updated my questions..how is it possible to move one step backward in box2d ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the problem when it only works once is because you never reset your BOOLs from what I can tell. `Aistouched` and `Cistouched`. Try adding `Aistouched = FALSE` right after your set the `Bvelocity.x = 5;` and same for C.